# My first app run an ASP.NET core on ubuntu linux, failed to create symbolic link error?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, hyperlink

I have been trying to follow this tutorial.
[How to Run an ASP.NET Core on Linux](https://developingsoftware.com/aspnetcore-ubuntu/)
I am getting an error at this stage :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/hellomvc.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

error is

> ln: failed to create symbolic link './hellomvc.com.conf': File exists.

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Man is your friend

When discovering a new command like `ln`, it could be interesting to look at the manual:

```
man ln
```

It would have told you that `ln -s` create a symbolic link to a file.

#### Unix: Everything is a file

Even symbolic link is a file and obviously it means that if a file with the same name exists already in the same directory, `ln` won't overwrite it and will fail with a `File exists.` error.

If you want to execute the command at each build and create the link when there is no link already created, you should use test or [:

```
if [ ! -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/hellomvc.com.conf ]
then
    sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/hellomvc.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
fi
```

*By the way, it only checks that a file with the given name already exists and it doesn't check that the target of the link is the expected one.*